# Iterate over multiple divs and remove children of each div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs with the class `badge-partial`. I now wish to iterate over each of these divs and remove all children from each div. I have tried the following:

```
$(".badge-partial").each(function() {
  $(this).children().remove();
});
```

But this does not trigger anything.

Comment: Seems to work here.. http://jsfiddle.net/Lyycpd8u/

Comment: Probably forgot to wait until elements existed .. try `$(function(){ /* your code*/})`

Comment: It works fine. Wait while all children being removed.

Comment: Try it out, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/7k6ayyt7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/), you don't even need to iterate over all div ;

```
  $(".badge-partial").empty() ;
```

If you really want to use iteration and doing other stuffs :

```
$(".badge-partial").each(function() {
  $(this).empty() ; 

  // Do other stuff here 
});
```

Comment: But I would also prefer a solution where I do iterate over each element, so I can do other stuff to the element as well.